# Create a new factor/variable with levels based on "N" consecutive occurrences of original factor level

Tags: r, data.table

I've started a new project with a bunch of data management I've never had to do before, and I seemingly lack the skills or the appropriate search terms to find an example. I have a very large data set with a grouping variable and a binary event variable. It can be generalized to a working example as:

```
library('data.table')
grp <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
v1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
test<-data.frame(grp,v1)
test

   grp v1
1    a  1
2    a  0
3    a  0
4    a  1
5    a  1
6    a  1
7    a  1
8    b  1
9    b  0
10   b  0
11   b  0
12   b  1
```

I've been using `data.table` to label streaks of "v1" within unique levels of "grp" as events with a new ordinal numeric factor "event":

```
setDT(test)
test<-test[, .(v1 = v1, event = rleidv(v1)), by=grp]

    grp v1 event
 1:   a  1     1
 2:   a  0     2
 3:   a  0     2
 4:   a  1     3
 5:   a  1     3
 6:   a  1     3
 7:   a  1     3
 8:   b  1     1
 9:   b  0     2
10:   b  0     2
11:   b  0     2
12:   b  1     3
```

In the actual data set some of these "grp" specific events are very long and I need to break them up into smaller, variable, *n* - limited events. For example, my desired output for a new variable "sub.event" with *n* = 2 is:

```
> test
    grp v1 event sub.event
 1:   a  1     1         1
 2:   a  0     2         2
 3:   a  0     2         2
 4:   a  1     3         3
 5:   a  1     3         3
 6:   a  1     3         4
 7:   a  1     3         4
 8:   b  1     1         1
 9:   b  0     2         2
10:   b  0     2         2
11:   b  0     2         3
12:   b  1     3         4
```

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a way to do this. It seems simple enough that I must be missing something obvious. To help facilitate, the original variables can be concatenated into new variables before determining the *n*-limited "sub.event".

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method that works with chaining.

```
setDT(test)[, new := rep(1:0, length.out=.N), by=.(grp, rleid(v1))][,
              new := cumsum(new), by=grp]
```

The first chain returns a vector of 1s and 0s repeating the length of the grp-`rleid` pair. The next link in the chain sums this up with `cumsum` by grp.

this returns

```
test
    grp v1 new
 1:   a  1   1
 2:   a  0   2
 3:   a  0   2
 4:   a  1   3
 5:   a  1   3
 6:   a  1   4
 7:   a  1   4
 8:   b  1   1
 9:   b  0   2
10:   b  0   2
11:   b  0   3
12:   b  1   4
```

Note that as written, it doesn't automatically extend to n > 2. However, the piece that produces it, `1:0`  could be written `rep(c(1L, rep(0L, n)), length.out=.N)` where `n+1` is the number of repeated values that you'd want.

In this case, the code would look like

```
test[, new := rep(c(1L, rep(0L, 2L)), length.out=.N), by=.(grp, rleid(v1))][,
       new := cumsum(new), by=grp]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, going to try both of these this morning.

Comment: I like these convenience of changing *n* in this case. It kicks back a bunch of warnings. I'm just learning data.table, but I'm guessing it's when the "event" sub group is not divisible by my specified "n" and there's leftover strings that are discarded?

Comment: For the example data, you can set *n* to smaller or larger numbers and shouldn't get a warning. I tried 1, 2, and 12. without issue. The ultimate length of the `rep` vector is controlled by `length.out`, which is set to the length of the group.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had a copy paste error; "length.out=.N" was missing but it was still working with errors. Got it going perfectly now. Thanks a lot. I should be able to work through the code and the cheat sheet to see exactly how it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat roundabout:

```
# make counters within v1, grp
test[, v0 := rep(1:.N, each=2, length.out=.N), by=.(rleid(grp, v1))]

# make overall counters
test[, v := .GRP, by=rleid(grp, v1, v0)]

# difference per grp
test[, v := v - first(v) + 1L, by=grp]

# drop internal counter
test[, v0 := NULL ]

    grp v1 v
 1:   a  1 1
 2:   a  0 2
 3:   a  0 2
 4:   a  1 3
 5:   a  1 3
 6:   a  1 4
 7:   a  1 4
 8:   b  1 1
 9:   b  0 2
10:   b  0 2
11:   b  0 3
12:   b  1 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, going to try both of these this morning.